# Is it possible the create side-by-side chart in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I want a side by side bar chart using python, shown in the image below created using tableau. The column start_end is a string, the month is integer and mean_travel_time is float. I will appreciate the help. The image shows the chart created in tableau.

[image: 1]

I want that side-by-side chart using the generated groupeby output in 2nd output, so 0-7 should show 3 bar that is for month 1,2,3, and bar height should depend on their mean travel time value(x-axis "start_end" and y-axis "mean_travel_time")

1.Through this code, I have selected the three-column I wanted:

```
temp = df[["start_end", "month","mean_travel_time"]]
     temp.head()
Output:
start_end   month   mean_travel_time
0   19-0    1   1252.43
1   16-19   3   275.31
2   16-19   2   436.38
3   10-16   1   810.17
4   10-16   1   723.02
```

2."Grouped them using:"

```
y= temp.groupby(['start_end','month']).mean()
y
output:              
start_end   month   mean_travel_time  
0-7           1     773.065546
              2     756.826511
              3     625.543670
10-16         1     978.287189
              2     981.910590
              3     765.040125
16-19         1     987.947657
              2     985.739013
              3     731.957644
19-0          1     833.607821
              2     841.169819
              3     678.709235
7-10          1     967.038627
              2     963.907163
              3     722.351764
```

Comment: `y['mean_travel_time'].unstack('month').plot.bar()`?

Comment: It's working but that's not how I want it, can you look at the image above in the link?
Thanks in advance. :)